# É necessário usar as tags ul e li no flexslider?

Tags: html, flexslider

Estou querendo saber se tem como trocar as ul e li por div ? Pq eu acho mais complicado mexer com ul e li do que com divs !!

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas o que tem de dificil em usar `<li>`? Pense no <ul> como o div pai e nos `<li>`s como divs filhas. Poderia explicar a dificuldade? Acredito que nao tem como trocar.

Comment: é que não consigo colocar a ordem no css !!ex: slide li{} ou slide ul{} ou quando usar slide ul li{}

Comment: É so trocar o [selector dele](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/): `selector: ".slides > li", `.

Comment: não entendi ? bruno.

Comment: @BrunoWego Faz sentido, formule uma resposta, com um exemplo um pouco mais completo. Otima dica (apesar de nao ter testado ainda).

Comment: @GilmarSantos que ordem? Poderia explicar **editando** a pergunta? Nao entendo o que mudar pra div ira melhorar no uso da ordem.

Comment: é que não consigo mexer com a tag ul e li. no html eu sei mexer, mas, no css não consigo.

Comment: Esta ainda dificil de entender, a tag ul no css seria `ul {}` e no div `div {}`, no li seria `ul > li {}` e no div `div > div {}`, so muda os nomes. Seu problema parece coisa, isto nao tem nada haver com o ordenamento que voce citou anteriormente, a ordem nao e influenciada por divs ou lis ou uls. Poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: vlw vou estudar mais sobre as tags li e ul !! ainda sou muito leigo em linguagens web !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), basta alterar o parâmetro `selector`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      selector: ".slides > li"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Isso se torna possível pois o flexslider utiliza classes em seus elementos filhos e não a seleção pelo elemento `li`.

Comment: a entendi é so eu mudar esse selector: ".slides > li" para selector: ".slides > div"